# Createdb does not create a db in postgres: no error message

Tags: postgresql

When I try to create a db in postgres 9.3, it does not create the database. I do not get any error messages.

```
abramhandler-# createdb orleansgis
abramhandler-# \list
                                         List of databases
     Name     |    Owner     | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |       Access privileges       
--------------+--------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-------------------------------
 abramhandler | abramhandler | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres     | abramhandler | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0    | abramhandler | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/abramhandler              +
              |              |          |             |             | abramhandler=CTc/abramhandler
 template1    | abramhandler | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/abramhandler              +
              |              |          |             |             | abramhandler=CTc/abramhandler
(4 rows)

abramhandler-#
```

I tried entering `#commit` and it still does not show the database.

The [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-createdb.html) show how to debug error messages -- but I'm not sure what to do when I get no error message at all. It simply does not create the database.

Comment: SQL statements in `psql` need to be terminated with a `;` - but `createdb` is not a SQL command it's a commandline program. From within `psql` you would need to run `create database orleansgis;` (don't forget the `;`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`createdb` is a shell command line command. At the psql client prompt use the [`create database`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdatabase.html) command

When the prompt is `-#` it is still waiting for the command termination, a semicolon. Enter `Ctrl C` to escape that.